# How to make a popup script with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I need to make a script in pure JS for showing an popup when the page is loaded.
The background needs to be faded and i have to add my own content into the popup.
I don't want to use CSS or HTML.
Put the CSS and HTML into the Javascript code.
Can someone help me with this?
I can do styling on my own.
I can only make an popup with external CSS and HTML, not pure JS.
It only must be a simple popup written in pure JS en it pops up when the page is loaded.

Please help me!!

I prefer the use of JSFiddle.

Comment: I don't know how to, thats why i'm asking :(

Comment: Where are you stuck in your efforts so far? You should put the code that's causing problems in the question, describe its intent, and what doesn't work. If you're getting errors, include those too

Comment: this doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/cn49qdpr/

Comment: Your intent is a bit unclear.  When you say you don't want to use CSS or HTML, does that include any styling/markup *generated by* the JavaScript?  If so, how do you plan to display content then?  If not, then are you just asking how to create elements with JavaScript and add them to the page?

Comment: Yes only styling/markup generated by the Javascript

Comment: @JelleBotman: In that case it sounds like what you're looking to do is create HTML elements in your JavaScript code and add them to the page.  This seems like a reasonable place to start:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement  Related Google searches will also find many examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated answer:

You can simply use `display` style property of css and on `onClick` of button hide/show `popup` style using css.

#### Updates

- add popup placeholder element in DOM
- add css for popup - see css provided in answer
- add pop DOM using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of JS and required JS for show/hide popup

Something like below -

```js
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it popup content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  newDiv.innerHTML +='<button class="open_button" onClick="openPopup()">Open Popup</button><div id="popup" style="  position: absolute;width: 300px;z-index: 999;display: none;top:0;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px #aaa;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 100px;">This is sample popuup</div><button class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">close</button</div>';   

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("main_container"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  // open popup onload
  openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  el.style.display = 'block';
  
  // Updates: set window background color black
  document.body.style.background = '#353333';
}

function closePopup() {
  var el = document.getElementById('popup');
  el.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.style.background = 'white';
}
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Comment: I can just include this script into my website?

Comment: of course, you can :)

Comment: I see, it only works when I include this at the bottom of my page.

Comment: How can I add a black background to the page when the pop-up shows up>

Comment: @JelleBotman you can do something like `document.body.style.background = 'black';`  or `document.body.style.background = '#353333';` See updated code.

Comment: I would like to have the background darker, but that you still see the website, that solution is not exactly what i wanted

Comment: Nice simple solution, very useful.